# Imported from Google Notebook?

Tags: google-drive, import

Today I logged in to my Google Docs and saw a mysterious looking file `Imported from Google Notebook - My Notebook`.

[image]

I have no idea what is Google Notebook or how it got there.
The content of the document seems blank.

Is it a bug, or I am hacked or something?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Google is closing the service called Google Notebook. All documents are automatically imported from this service into Google Docs. If you don't remember using it don't worry about it. You can safely remove this document.

Comment: This is exactly right. The blank document was imported from Google Notebook. You may have tried Google Notebook years ago when it was introduced, and left behind a blank notebook page, which was preserved and now has been moved to Google Docs.